# how to get timestamp from user input(FORM) to its actual data?

Tags: php, postgresql

let say I have a form:

```
<form ... >
<input type="text" name="date" /> //input here is 2013-06-14 09:00:00
</form>
```

I assigned it to let say:

```
$log = new record();
var_dump($log->timein = $_POST['date']); // OUTPUT is string(0) "" 

I tried using manual update:
var_dump($log->timein = '2013-06-14 09:00:00'); //string(19) "2013-06-14 06:00:00"
```

what will I do so that the `$log->timein` will get the value 2013-06-14 06:00:00 and not just empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
if( isset($_POST['date']) && trim($_POST['date']) != '' ) {
  $log->timein = $_POST['date'];
} else {
  $log->timein = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: still I get an empty string.

Comment: I still got a dump of NULL. wew

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just check for [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and not [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) before declaring your variable

```
if(isset($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['date']))
{
      $log->timein = $_POST['date'];
}
```

Comment: @user2429302 Did you declare your variable as NULL or 'NULL'? Second one (note the quotes) is a string so it will be not empty.

Comment: I declared $log->timein = NULL; when I do $log->timein = $_POST['date'] it just dumps NULL. I want to get the exact value

Comment: Try to add in if clauses != NULL like `if(isset($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['date']) && ($_POST['date'] != NULL))`

Comment: @user2429302 did you try it?